# Javascript bottleneck for server communication (for downloading resources)

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a javascript application. In my application I want to create my own cache management.

Now my question is: Is there any bottleneck in javascript (e.g. any event on window object) that we can handle and modify all server communications?

many tags in the page can request a resource from server e.g. `img`, `link`, `script`.

In other words I want a bottleneck in javascript that I can be notified that a resource is requested from server. Then I will look into my cache-system and will serve the resource either from my cache or by downloading the content from a generic HTTP handler on my server.

I know it's a bit strange requirement but because I believe javascript is very flexible I though this "bottleneck" may exist.

Thank you.

Comment: So you want to be able to basically interrupt any http requests happening on a given page (the page being equivalent to your application)?  I think the only way to manually accomplish this is to programmatically retrieve any resources you want to handle the caching of - I dont' think there's any way to interrupt http requests...

Comment: Why do you want to do your own caching rather than relying on local HTTP (e.g. browser) caching? There are ways of doing this sort of thing and storing the results in localstorage but that's HTML5 only

Comment: @AndyDavies, you missed the point of the question, it's not about why or how to cache things, it's about having a bottleneck for all server requests of a HTML page. but: yes, i'm using HTML5.

Comment: @valipour I'm not sure there's any reliable way of doing this but have a look through the work stevesouders does - at one point he had a script that tried to change all the JS on a page so that it loaded async, you may be able to use something similar to inject your own resource handler.

Answer (score 0):

One way to lazy load resources is to set a common source (eg. 1.gif for images, x.txt for script/css) pointing at small, cacheable resources.  Then set a data attribute on the element with the actual path to the content.

```
<img src="/1.gif" data-url="/images/puppies.png" class="onhold" />
```

Finally, on domready or document load you could do your logic to set the proper urls, replace dom element, etc.  Using jQuery you'd do something like this -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("img.onhold").each(function() {
    var img = $(this),
    url = img.data("url");

    // any logic to update url based on cache, CDN, etc. here
    img.attr("src", url);
  });
});
```

Comment: This has two problems: (1) I think this way browser still sends a request to the server (because you have src) (2) there are many cases this doesn't cover like when your image is created by script etc.